# How to use pygame.time.get_ticks() to do a delay without effecting the user input

Tags: python, windows, loops, if-statement, pygame

So I'm making a constellation which starts from (0,0) to wherever I left click and the previous line should disappear after a 2-second delay.  During 2 secs, left clicks will not become a line but shown as white circles.

Right now I have a problem with making white circles showing on my code:

```py
# left clicked lines were more than 1 & been less than 2 secs    
            if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and time.get_ticks() - times <= 2000:   
                # Gets position of the mouse
                circleX, circleY = mouse.get_pos() 
                # the white circles appear 
                draw.circle (screen, WHITE, (circleX, circleY), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pygames event mechanics and `pygame.time.set_timer()`
Do something like this:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 2000)
```

and then in the event loop look for the event type.

```
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
```

When you detect the event the timer has expired and you do what you need to. A new timer can be set whenever some thing happens that you want to delay from (like your left click).

If you need multiple timers going and need to tell them apart, you can create an event with an attribute that you can set to different values to track them. Something like this (though I have not run this particular code snippet, so there could be a typo):

```
my_event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {"tracker": something})
pygame.time.set_timer(my_event , 2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a start time with

```
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

then every frame, check if it has been 2 seconds

```
if pygame.time.get_ticks() - start > 2000:
    #been 2 seconds
    start = pygame.time.get_ticks() #reset the timer
```

Comment: so should this be in my game loop ?

Comment: Yep, or in an update function of a class. As long as it gets called every iteration of the loop/frame. you want to check it as often as you can so it will run as soon as its been 2 seconds

Comment: how do I make my previous line disappear, am i suppose to make my line become the colour of my background (black)?

Comment: @SehunOoh You need to post your code, you need to stop drawing the line but without your code i cant help much more. But i would have a list that had the points to draw the lines to and after the 2 seconds i would delete the points in the list. So you can have mutiple lines at once

Comment: `pygame.time.get_ticks()` returns milliseconds, so you need to check `> 2000`.

Comment: @Kingsley whoops, thanks